# SQL MS ACCESS Create an Alias using Multiplication of Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, alias

Hello I am having trouble making a new Column "Alias" in my SQL code by multiplying two column values.

Question:

> 4. Compose a query to show every product that has a value of $400 or more. The value of each product is defined as the quantity on hand
>      multiplied by the unit price of that product. In the result table,
>      show product ID, unit price, quantity on hand, and the product value.
>      Sort the results by the product value in descending order.

My Code:

```
Select Product_ID, Unit_Price, On_Hand, **Unit_Price * On_Hand as Product_Value**
From Product_T
Where Product_Value >= 400.00
Group by Product_ID
Order by (Product_Value) desc
```

I keep getting an error message saying:

"Your Query does not include the specified expression 'unit price' as part of an aggregate function"

Any idea on how to overpass this?

Comment: Do you need the group by in there? That seems unnecessary, since you aren't using SUM() or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an aggregation is needed.  If not, you need to repeat the expression in the `where` (or use a subquery):

```
Select Product_ID, Unit_Price, On_Hand,
       (Unit_Price * On_Hand) as Product_Value
From Product_T
Where (Unit_Price * On_Hand) >= 400.00
Order by (Unit_Price * On_Hand) desc;
```

If an aggregation is needed, then you want a `having` clause:

```
Select Product_ID, 
       sum(Unit_Price * On_Hand) as Product_Value
From Product_T
Group by Product_ID
Having sum(Unit_Price * On_Hand) >= 400.00
Order by sum(Unit_Price * On_Hand) desc;
```